# Css ::after NOT displaying on same line for link text as applied using Twig

Tags: html, css, twig, drupal-8, clearfix

The problem:

I’m trying to automate adding something to the end of the link text on a Drupal 8 site that uses twig with the ::after CSS function. Something like:

```
    &::after {
     content: '!!!!';
}
```

Although the content is being outputted on the page it is being added on the next line when the display is set to ‘display=block’. In other words the html in the Chrome console looks like:

```
::before
<div>
     a Twig output <a href=”http://link>Link Title Text</a> 
</div>
::after
```

And looks like:

```
Link Title Text
Continuation of Link Title Text
!!!!
```

What I’d like the output to look like is:

```
Link Title Text
Continuation of Link Title Text!!!!
```

The closest I’ve gotten to figure this out is to change the display to ‘display: inline-flex’. This might work ok if the Title Text were only on one line. HOWEVER, the title text to the links often take 2 (or more) lines so the result in that case is:

```
Link Title Text             !!!!
Continuation of  Link Title Text
```

Instead of the desired:

```
Link Title Text
Continuation of Link Title Text!!!!
```

To complicate things I noticed that changing from ‘display: block’ to ‘display: inline-flex’ added addition spacing above and below that will not work for the styling of the page.

I’m assuming that the ::after is being applied to the ‘href=’ and not the  title of for the link. Is it possible to apply the ::after to the title text of the link instead of the ‘href=’ link to get the desired outcome?

The Twig relevant Twig code looks something like this:

```
<div>{% for linktitle in linktitle_arr %}<a {{ attributes.addClass(link_classes) }} target="_blank" href="{{url_}}">{{linktitle.value}}</a>{% endfor %}</div>
```

Any insight is much appreciated.

- UPDATE - SOLUTION - UPDATE -

Just wanted to update this post with what I discovered and how I ‘solved’ this.

The problem didn’t end up being with Twig as I had originally suspected. This is a ‘clear-fix hack’ issue. If you are not familiar the code/hack looks like this:

```
@mixin clearfix() {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " "; // 1
    display: table; // 2
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
```

The root of the problem is the use of ‘display: table’ which drops the attached pseudo element ‘below’ the parent element into a new column, rather than along the same row, as expected, and as described above in my original question.

If you run into this issue and you use clear-fix you’ll have to modify it for your particular use-case. In my case I solved this while raising new issues to deal with as a result which are outside the scope of this update. Whack-a-mole.

It should also be noted that in my particular case the page in question is a custom theme built on a Bootstrap 3 sub-theme. Bootstrap itself utilizes the full clear-fix code, HOWEVER, there is also a modified version of it deep inside Drupal core that was influencing the proper expected function of the :after pseudo element as well.

You can find the Drupal core clear-fix at:

/core/modules/system/css/components/clearfix.module.css

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo element of that **a** tag.

Twig:

```
<div>{% for linktitle in linktitle_arr %}<a {{ attributes.addClass(link_classes) }} target="_blank" href="{{url_}}">{{linktitle.value}}</a>{% endfor %}</div>
```

CSS:

```
a::after {
  content: '!!!!';
}
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/eliortabeka/pen/rNMPQRP

Should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I had hoped it was going to be just as simple as you would think, but seems like the more simple the task in theory on this site, the opposite ends up being the case. Check above for the end solution and explanation.